# Mapping points using ggmap

Tags: r, mapping, ggmap, geom-point

Data is

```
> head(latlon1.df)
       lat       lon
1 35.86417 -95.65556
2 29.72333 -98.69444
3 29.52917 -97.46417
4 40.82806 -72.86556
5 26.73500 -81.05111
6       NA        NA
```

```
ggmap(usa) +
  geom_point(data = latlon1.df, mapping = aes(x = latlon1.df$lon, y = latlon1.df$lat), color = "red",size=1)
```

Keeping getting

```
mapping: x = ~latlon1.df$lon, y = ~latlon1.df$lat 
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
```

and I do not get a map or points
The map was loaded with ggmap and works correctly as a map but the points do not appear on the map
position_identity

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not a [reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) because you don't provide either the library from which `ggmap` is called [minor] nor (a sample) of the `usa` dataset (or a reference to where it can be obtained) [major]. Also, please use `dput()` or  `dput(head())` to post uour input data rather than `head()`.

Not everyone is familiar with every R package.  Please help yourself by helping us to help you.

That said, I susdepct youir problem is the syntax you are using in your `geom_point`.  I suspect you don't need to repeat the data frame name in thecall to `aes`.  Here's a reprex demonstrating the correct usage when using different data sources in different geoms.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

x <- tibble(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
y <- tibble(x=c(0, 1), y=c(0, 1))

x %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line(data=y, aes(x=x, y=y), colour="red")
```

[image]